# How would I select records in a database and insert them into another in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to copy records from one database to another and narrow them down by Type. That is, all records with the type "Holiday" will be copied. When I run this statement, however, I get an error.

MySQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO nfb_events.nfb_events(`ID`, `Name`, `Type`, `Host`, `Location`, `Date`, `StartTime`, `EndTime`, `Description`)
SELECT * FROM eagles_events.eagles_events WHERE `Type`="Holiday";
```

Error:

```
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'Type' at row 1
```

I don't understand; the "Type" record is a Varchar with a length of only 10 characters. I am using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Post output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE nfb_events.nfb_events; SHOW CREATE TABLE eagles_events.eagles_events;`

Comment: Do you mean from one **table** to another **table** because at the command line you have to enter **use databasename** to switch from operating on one database to another database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by explicitly naming the columns in the `select *`:

```
INSERT INTO nfb_events.nfb_events(`ID`, `Name`, `Type`, `Host`, `Location`, `Date`,
                                  `StartTime`, `EndTime`, `Description`)
    SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `Type`, `Host`, `Location`, `Date`, `StartTime`, `EndTime`, `Description`
    FROM eagles_events.eagles_events
    WHERE `Type`= 'Holiday';
```

One possibility is that the columns are created in a different order in the two tables, so this ensures that the right data is going to the right column.

If this doesn't work, check the types of all the columns in each table to be sure they are the same.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I had two colums switched around! Thanks a lot!